# hyperlink cell in GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt

I have a cell table in GWT with textcells and buttoncell ,Now i want to add a hyperlinkCell in my celltable , is this possible ?

```
                  TextCell jobStatusCell = new TextCell();
    jobStatusColumn = new Column<EmployerJobs, String>(jobStatusCell) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(EmployerJobs object) {

            // int status = object.getJobStatusId();
            /*
             * if(status ==1) { return ""; } else
             */
            // return "post job";
            return "view";
        }
    };
```

I want some thing like this

```
             HyperlinkCell jobStatusCell = new HyperLinkCell();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean this [HyperlinkCell](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/listwidget/client/ui/HyperlinkCell.java?spec=svn12&r=12)?

If not, you can write a normal hyperlink (`<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">linkCell </a>`)and put it as the content of a cell.

Comment: Is hyperlink cell still a thing? your link takes me elsewhere.

Comment: @StealthRabbi The asker never confirmed which HyperlinkCell he meant. GWT never provided one So I just googled and put the first one. But again, I am not sure this is the one he was using

Comment: Nevertheless, the link you have in your answer doesn't take me to something that has a class called HyperlinkCell. At least, I can't find it in the source link.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following Cell implementation

Be sure that you provide cell's value as an array of 2 String objects like:

```
String[] value = new String[2];
value[HyperTextCell.LINK_INDEX] = "http://www.google.com";
value[HyperTextCell.TEXT_INDEX] = "Search on google";

public class HyperTextCell extends AbstractCell<String[]> {

interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>")
    SafeHtml hyperText(SafeUri link, String text);
}

private static Template template;

public static final int LINK_INDEX = 0, URL_INDEX = 1;

/**
 * Construct a new ImageCell.
 */
public HyperTextCell() {

    if (template == null) {
        template = GWT.create(Template.class);
    }
}

@Override
public void render(Context context, String[] value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value != null) {

        // The template will sanitize the URI.
        sb.append(template.hyperText(UriUtils.fromString(value[LINK_INDEX]), value[URL_INDEX]));
    }
    }
}
```